# Unable to find cppunitd.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cppunit

Okay so I built cppunit with visual sutdi 2010. The problem is when I try to compile one of the examples, I get a link error saying it cannot find a lib file, cppunitd.lib. I did a search using 'where' and was unable to find it. So I don't know what else to do since I already built it.

Comment: Did you generate the debug libs for cppunit? And made sure that the directory with the library is in your search path for your project?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how you would do any of these things.

Comment: You should build the cppunit libs with the debug configuration. x86 debug in the Cppunit Configuration view. For the search path for libs you need to look into the configuration as well to see where your project picks up libraries.